# Date in string to LocalDateTime conversion in java

Tags: java

DateTimes in different formats is always a problem for me. I have a date with the datatype string like `"2021-07-25"`

I want to convert this date to the datatype LocalDateTime in the format `2021-07-25T00:00:00.000-05:00`. I have the get and set property like below

```
private LocalDateTime relationshipStatusDate;

public LocalDateTime getRelationshipStatusDate() {
    return relationshipStatusDate;
}

public void setRelationshipStatusDate(LocalDateTime relationshipStatusDate) {
    this.relationshipStatusDate = relationshipStatusDate;
}


public void setRelationshipStatusDate(String time) {
    if (time != null) {
        try {
            long epochTime = Long.parseLong(time);
            this.relationshipStatusDate = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(epochTime), ZoneOffset.UTC);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e){
            this.relationshipStatusDate = LocalDateTime.parse(time, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
        }
    }
}
```

and I am trying to format like below and its failing with an error `"Unknown pattern letter T"`

```
  DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00.000-05:00");
  LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(statusDate, formatter);
```

Comment: Parse the input to a `LocalDate` and then use that to create a `LocalDateTime` with a `LocalTime.MIN` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your format won't be parsable as it doesn't support default values like `T00:00:00.000-05:00`. You *could* escape literals e.g. use `'T00:00...'` but that would just make the parser ignore them.

Instead, if all you get is a date then only parse a date and add the default time after that, e.g. like this:

```
 DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")    
 LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(statusDate, formatter );
 LocalDateTime dateTime = date.atStartOfDay(); //"relative" representation as the absolute instant would require adding a timezone
 ZonedDateTime zonedDT = date.atSTartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC); //"absolute" representation of instant
```

> I want to convert this date to the datatype LocalDateTime in the format 2021-07-25T00:00:00.000-05:00.

Note the potential misconception here: `LocalDateTime` does NOT have a format. It represents a date and time (from a local point of reference - not in absolute terms as the timezone is missing) and provides access to individual fields such as day of month, day of week etc. but it is not formatted. Formatting is applied when you convert that date object to a string.

Comment: LocalDateTime dateTime = date.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC); is being forced to change to ZonedDateTime.. :(

Comment: I think that can either be corrected by `LocalDateTime.of(date, LocalTime.MIN)` or switching to a `ZonedDateTime`, your decision, @challengeAccepted

Comment: @challengeAccepted you could use `atStartOfDay()` which returns a `LocalDateTime` but as the part "local" implies it's not a fixed instant based on a timezone. If you want to have the instant in the UTC timezone you need to use `ZonedDateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```java
LocalDate                           // Represent a date-only value, without a time-of-day and without a time zone or offset-from-UTC.         
.parse( "2021-07-25" )              // Parse a string in standard ISO 8601 format to instantiate a `LocalDate` object.
.atStartOfDay(                      // Determine the first moment of the day on that date in that zone. NB: The day does *not* always begin at 00:00, so never assume that time.
    ZoneId.of( "America/Bogota" )   // Real time zones have a name in Continent/Region format. Never use 2-4 letter pseudo-zones such as `CST` or `IST`. 
)                                   // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object, a moment in the context of a time zone.
.toOffsetDateTime()                 // Strips away the time zone information, leaving only a date with time-of-day in a particular offset. Returns an `OffsetDateTime` object.
.toString()                         // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

> 2021-07-25T00:00-05:00

## Details

### `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class

You said:

> datatype `LocalDateTime` in the format 2021-07-25T00:00:00.000-05:00

That is a contradiction. The `-05:00` at the end of your string is an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). A `LocalDateTime` object has no offset.

You seem to misunderstand the purpose of [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html). That class does *not* represent a moment as seen through the wall-clock time with an offset-from-UTC used by the people of a particular region. For that purpose, use `OffsetDateTime`, or preferably, `ZonedDateTime`.

Use **documentation rather than intuition** when programming with unfamiliar classes. To quote the Javadoc for `LocalDateTime`:

> A date-time without a time-zone … such as 2007-12-03T10:15:30.
>
> …
>
> This class does not store or represent a time-zone. Instead, it is a description of the date, as used for birthdays, … It cannot represent an instant on the time-line …

Here is my chart to summarize the types. Three classes represent a moment, while `LocalDateTime` does not.

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

You said:

> I have a date with the datatype string like "2021-07-25"

So use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) to represent that value.

By default, the *java.time* classes use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format when parsing/generating text. So no need to specify a formatting pattern here, as your input complies with that standard.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2021-07-25" ) ;
```

You said:

> I want to convert this date to … the format 2021-07-25T00:00:00.000-05:00

Your example there uses only a mere offset rather than a time zone. I suggest you use a time zone whenever possible.

An [offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) is simply a number of hours-minutes-seconds, nothing more. A [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) is much more. A time zone is a history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by people of a particular region, as decided by their politicians.

### `ZoneId`

So specify your time zone using [`Continent/Region` naming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

```java
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Cancun" );
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

Let *java.time* determine the first moment of the day on that date as seen in that time zone. Be aware that the day does *not* always start at 00:00. So never hard-code that time-of-day; let *java.time* do the work here.

```java
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( z ); // Determine the first moment of the day as seen in that zone. Not always 00:00.
```

Generate text to represent the value inside our [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). The [`ZonedDateTime#toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#toString()) method generates text in a format that wisely extends the ISO 8601 format by appending the name of the time zone in square brackets.

```java
String output = zdt.toString();
```

> 2021-07-25T00:00-05:00[America/Cancun]

Pull all that code together.

```java
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2021-07-25" );
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Cancun" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( z ); // Determine the first moment of the day as seen in that zone. Not always 00:00.
String output = zdt.toString();
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/M3aE15).

> 2021-07-25T00:00-05:00[America/Cancun]

### `OffsetDateTime`

If you insist on generating text in your stated format, while omitting the name of the time zone, use [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

```
String output = zdt.toOffSetDateTime().toString() ;
```

All of these topics have been covered many times on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.